# How to count the occurrence of specific words in a Mysql db row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm quite new to MySQL. I require to count the number of occurrences of specific words in a MySQL table/columns.

I came across the following code through another post @Raging Bull, which only provides the count of one specific word.

```
SELECT name,(CHAR_LENGTH(description)-
    CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(description,' is ','')))/CHAR_LENGTH(' is ') AS 
TotalCount
FROM TableName
GROUP BY name
```

Could someone help me to align it for multiple words to be counted. For example, I want to count "is", "as", "was", "how".

Comment: What would the desired result look like? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: See there's an edit button

Comment: word |s Count
-s is  |s 10
-s how |s 15
-s was s| 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `LENGTH` instead of `CHAR_LENGTH` and truncate spaces from String, e.g.:

```
SELECT name,
    ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(description)
            - LENGTH(REPLACE(description, "is", "")) 
        ) / LENGTH("is")        
    ) AS count
FROM TableName
```

**update**

To count multiple words, you can write simillar `ROUND` queries and add them together, e.g.:

```
SELECT name,
    SELECT(
        ROUND((LENGTH(description)- LENGTH(REPLACE(description, "is", "")) ) / LENGTH("is")) +
        ROUND((LENGTH(description)- LENGTH(REPLACE(description, "This", "")) ) / LENGTH("This")) +
        ROUND((LENGTH(description)- LENGTH(REPLACE(description, "That", "")) ) / LENGTH("That")) 
        ) AS `count`
FROM TableName
```

**update 2**

Here's the query to get the counts as individual columns:

```
SELECT name,
ROUND((LENGTH(description)- LENGTH(REPLACE(description, "is", "")) ) / LENGTH("is")) AS 'is count',
ROUND((LENGTH(description)- LENGTH(REPLACE(description, "this", "")) ) / LENGTH("this")) AS 'this count',
ROUND((LENGTH(description)- LENGTH(REPLACE(description, "by", "")) ) / LENGTH("by")) AS 'by count'
```

FROM TableName

**update 3**

Below is the query to get aggregated counts for words:

```
SELECT 'is', SUM(ROUND((LENGTH(description)- LENGTH(REPLACE(description, "is", "")) ) / LENGTH("is"))) AS `count` FROM TableName

UNION

SELECT 'this', SUM(ROUND((LENGTH(description)- LENGTH(REPLACE(description, "this", "")) ) / LENGTH("this"))) AS `count` FROM TableName

UNION

SELECT 'by', SUM(ROUND((LENGTH(description)- LENGTH(REPLACE(description, "by", "")) ) / LENGTH("by"))) AS `count` FROM TableName
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f47af/20/0)**.

Comment: I need the count of multiple words. As to your code, i require words like
-test
-is

the count of multiple words sir

Comment: In the code only, "is" is being calculated. I require multiple words to be calculated. 
Like, in this sentence : How are you doing today?

the result should have - How: 1 ; are: 1; you; 1

Comment: @JohnWix Added query to count multiple words.

Comment: I still get an error running it sir. Could you please double check.

Comment: One more thing, could you tell me how I could show the corresponding values of "is", "this" and "that" within the table, removing the "Test1" and "Test2" on the first column. so it will be like is ---> 04 (count) this ----> 05 (count) that ----> 04 (count)

Comment: You can remove outer query and write another `SELECT` with individual `ROUND` queries to get the counts for respective words as I mentioned in the first answer.

Comment: I'm so sorry but could you please show me how to do it. Kinda new programming. Thanks

Comment: Also is there anyway to get all three counts in one table as the query sir?

Comment: Added another query

Comment: @DarshanMetha
The new query does not seem to work sir. would you able to check? It provides the following error.

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT(ROUND((LENGTH(description)- LENGTH(REPLACE(description, "is", "")) ) / LE' at line 2

Comment: @DarshanMetha 
Works!
I'm so sorry for asking this again and again, but is there away to get the total of each count sir? rather than the specific count of each row.

Please Check this link for the outcome: https://ibb.co/jbTPgQ

Comment: Added another query

Comment: Its Perfect! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is not designed for this sort of thing.  However, you can just add the values together.  I thing the correct method is like this;

```
select ( (length(concat(' ', description, ' ')) - length(replace(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' is ', '')) / length(' is ') +
         (length(concat(' ', description, ' ')) - length(replace(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' as ', '')) / length(' as ') +
         (length(concat(' ', description, ' ')) - length(replace(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' was ', '')) / length(' was ') +
         (length(concat(' ', description, ' ')) - length(replace(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' how ', '')) / length(' how ')
        )
from t ;
```

Note the use of spaces at the beginning and end to capture words at the beginning and end of the description.  Also, this assumes that only spaces are used for separating words.

Comment: @Strawberry how could regex be included. Could you post the code please. I'm quite new

Comment: @JohnWix I think I'm mixing up with MariaDB - which has wider support for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(adm_no)  from class_manager
```

Try that where `adm_no` is the column name and  `class_manager` is the table